# How to fix these broken packages?

Tags: apt, package-management

After I saw an error message in the panel, I ran `sudo apt-get -f install`, which gave me the output below. It obviously mentions some issues. How can I fix this?

```
sai@Blu-Sky:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bluez-cups printer-driver-gutenprint printer-driver-splix ubuntu-minimal
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 4 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
6 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 1250 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_IN:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "en_IN"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
Can't exec "locale": No such file or directory at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 16.
Use of uninitialized value $Debconf::Encoding::charmap in scalar chomp at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/Encoding.pm line 17.
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: Dumping a load of output != asking a question. At least provide some context as a starting point to start reading it, use a proper title etc.

Comment: Issuing the command `which ldconfig` tells me that it lives in `/sbin`  "Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin"  does it? Please review http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: there are 4 broken packges,how can i fix them

Comment: Hi sai, better, but essential information is how you got there in the first place. Specific things you did?

Comment: I have an error notification in taskbar and search how to fix then i found that error in terminal

Comment: If you add that to the question as a description, you have an actual question :). I assume you mean the red triangle?

Comment: Jacob Vlijm sir i am new to ubuntu and not aware of all these.pls tell me how can i fix those broken packages.

Comment: That is not my speciality, but if we first fix the question and get rid of the -5, good chance it will attract someone who can help you.

Comment: For this you need to set locales with `locale-gen en_IN en_IN.UTF-8` and then `dpkg-reconfigure locales` Probably best to also included `en_US en_US.UTF-8` with the 1st command. If that errors out something else is wrong ... and we need to know the error it gives ;)

Comment: By the way: the problem is probably something completely else so can you add something to your question: the results of `history`.

Comment: i can't set locales because of broken packages,i don't have locale package and error while installing.

Answer (score 1):

Open a terminal and input the following:

```
sudo aptitude install language-pack-en

sudo aptitude install locales
```